# Outlook VBA Restrict on All Items

Tags: vba, outlook

I was hoping to find a way to get an Outlook items collection for all items, regardless of what folder they may be sitting in so I can do a restrict on every item, no matter where someone may have moved it. Does anyone know if this is possible? I was poking around in the Outlook object model but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Examples https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4539709%20%5bvba%5d%20Restrict

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application.AdavncedSearch to search the top level folder of the store including subfolders. Keep in mind that the search is asynchronous, so you will need to wait for the Application.AdvancedSearcvhComplete event to fire.